# How to connect Arduino to Raspberry through USB-TTL (called like this in electronics shops)?

Tags: usb, serial, arduino

I want to connect an Arduino to Raspberry Pi through a **USB-TTL converter** like this one:

[image: converter]

My doubt would be about logic voltage. I know that Arduino works with 5V logic, while Raspberry Pi does with 3.3V and is non-tolerant. So, **how should the wiring be done?**

I'm not intending to connect any weird stuff to the Raspberry. To the Raspberry Pi is only going to go the usb-end of the adapter.

My adapter does not have a serial number to identify it, but its main chip does, it is this:

https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/cp2102.pdf

I just want to avoid damaging the Pi through USB. I don't know if supplying 5V through it might damage it, though.

Basically just want to know if should be this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

References I used for documenting:

- https://deepbluembedded.com/usb-ttl-converter-tutorial-pc-control-for-microcontrollers/
- https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Access-Headless-Raspberry-Pi-Using-USB-to-T/

Comment: I am suspicious of any Instructables post. Many are poor quality. There are plenty of good Pi tutorials on this site & raspberrypi.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after getting better documented and performing tests, I got the right wiring for **avoid damaging the Raspberry Pi** and getting the desired **serial communication** as expected.

**USB** standard gives **5V max** output (considering the possible threshold) which by design **would not damage the Pi**. Which is not the case for **GPIOs**, where if you would like to do something similar, you **should use a level shifter** since those are **not 5V tolerant**.

Here is the right wiring:

[image: solution]

Answer (score 0):

First that device is NOT TTL (it would be CMOS).

No one can tell what it does from a picture. You need to check the specifications. Many (most?) such devices actually output 3.3V logic.

IMPORTANT DO NOT connect ANY power pins 3.3 or 5V to the Pi!

Comment: The USB chip my adapter uses is https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/cp2102.pdf seems like the adapter does not have serial number. I was not asking about how to wire something to the pi. The pi is going to only get the usb-end plugged.

Comment: If you are planning to connect USB to the Pi the Question makes no sense. USB is 5V. NOTE the Instructables post is pin connections to the Pi.

Comment: Yes, I thought that, but I concerned when I read about Pi not being 5V tolerant. Sorry for my ignorance. Could you confirm only with my latest updates on the question? I posted my wiring options.

Comment: I EDITED the post, as you might see. My question is intended to AVOID damaging the RASPBERRY.

Answer (score 0):

Connect like this:

```
Arduino - USB Serial
Txd     - Rxd
Rxd     - Txd
GND     - GND
```

Do NOT connect any power pins.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly the way to do it. Thanks.